# How to call a base method that is declared as abstract override

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding, abstract

In C# it's possible to mark a virtual method abstract to force inherited class to implement it.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A method call");
    }
}

abstract class B : A
{
    // Class inherited from B are forced to implement Method.
    public abstract override void Method();
}
```

I would like to call the `A` implementation of `Method` from a class inherited from `B`.

```
class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        // I would like to call A implementation of Method like this:
        // base.base.Method();
    }
}
```

The best way I find to do this is to add a protected method "MethodCore" in A implementation and call it when needed.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        MethodCore();
    }

    protected void MethodCore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A method call");
    }
}

abstract class B : A
{
    public abstract override void Method();
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        MethodCore();
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best way I find to do this is to add a protected method "MethodCore" in A implementation and call it when needed.

Yes. Since you can't call an `abstract` method using `base`, all possible solutions are going to require you to eventually call `Method` in `A` using an `A` instance.

That said, it looks like you are looking for a way to provide a *default* implementation of `Method` in `B` such that any subclass of `B` that does not implement the method should simply use the implementation present in `A`. A better solution would be to not mark `Method` as `abstract` in `B`. Instead, make `Method` in `B` redirect to `Method` in `A` using `base.Method()`

```
abstract class B : A {
// Class inherited from B are forced to implement Method.
   public virtual void Method() { 
        base.Method()//calls Method in A
   }
}
```

This way, any subclass of `B` that wants to call `Method` from `A` can simply say `base.Method()`.

Comment: And of course if I want a specific implementation I just have to provide it. But I loose the "you must provide an implementation" benefit...

Comment: @Orace Unfortunately, a method in a parent class can't be optional and mandatory to implement at the same time.